# How does a node point to the next?

Tags: python, list, linked-list

In a linked list implementation in python, we do something like:

```py
first_node.next = second_node
```

Now here, `second_node` is an object of class `create_node()`. However, `first_node.next` is one of the arguments of this class.

Now with above mentioned line of code, are we just assigning the object, `second_node` to the attribute `first_node.next` or are we pointing the address of the `second_node` object to the `first_node.next` attribute?

It's confusing me. How does it work?

Answer (score 0):

When this code executes:

```
first_node.next = second_node
```

...then `first_node.next` (which is an *attribute* of `first_node`) will *reference* the same node as `second_node`.

I'll assume this code as context:

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None

first_node = Node(10)
second_node = Node(20)
first_node.next = second_node
```

NB: It would be strange to call the class `create_node`. It is not common practice to use a verb here. Classes do more than just create things, so just name it by the instance you get from them, and use PascalCase. So `Node`.

Now to what this code does. It may help to visualise it.

1. Create `first_node`

   ```py
   first_node = Node(10)
   ```

   ```
    first_node
       ↓
   ┌────────────┐
   │ value: 10  │
   │ next: None │
   └────────────┘
   ```
2. Create `second_node`

   ```py
   second_node = Node(20)
   ```

   ```
    first_node              second_node
       ↓                        ↓
   ┌────────────┐           ┌────────────┐
   │ value: 10  │           │ value: 20  │
   │ next: None │           │ next: None │
   └────────────┘           └────────────┘
   ```
3. Link the first to the second

   ```py
   first_node.next = second_node
   ```

   ```
    first_node              second_node
       ↓                        ↓
   ┌────────────┐           ┌────────────┐
   │ value: 10  │           │ value: 20  │
   │ next: ───────────────► │ next: None │
   └────────────┘           └────────────┘
   ```

Comment: Thanks trincot ,for quick reply. what i am confused at is the "Link" you mentioned in point 3. What kind of link is made between first_node and second_node. Does next attribute of first_node store address ( reference) of second_node . or it stores complete second_node object.

Comment: No object is copied. Like in the visualisation there are two Node instances, not three. The arrows are references. So if after step 3 you would do `first_node.next.value = 30` then that would have the same effect as doing `second_node.value = 30`. If you would do `first_node.next = None` then this has no influence on anything that `second_node` is referencing.